# Clustering algorithm for multisorted data

Tags: clustering

I have two sets (“sorts”) $A$ and $B$, and a multiset $R$ whose underlying set is a subset of $A \times B$. I need a clustering algorithm, where each generated cluster consists of two subsets $S \subset A$ and $T \subset B$, and, given $x \in S$ and $y \in T$, then $(x,y)$ is likely to occur “very frequently” in $R$. As usual with clustering algorithms, clusters should be disjoint: given distinct clusters $(S,T)$ and $(S',T')$, then $S \cap S' = T \cap T' = \emptyset$.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Please check if my simple-word understanding is correct. You have actually a rectangular frequency matrix R defined by rows A and columns B. You want to form some disjoint "clusters" whose elements are cells of R - the (x,y) pairs - with "high" value (frequency). Am I right so far? Now, what I don't understand is what measure makes the clusters tight within a cluster and dispart between clusters. Say, what makes (x2,y14) and (x6,y3) similar to be in one cluster and dissimilar from (x5,y8) to keep it in another cluster?

Comment: I perceive, that any two clusters must have, as you request, completely different subscripts (i.e. x2, for example, may apper only in one cluster).

Comment: @ttnphns: “Am I right so far?” Yes. “What measure makes the clusters tight within a cluster and dispart between clusters?” What I'd like to maximize is the sum, ranging over all clusters, of some measure of each cluster's “mass”. The simplest such measure, for an individual cluster $(S,T)$, would be $\sum_{x \in S} \sum_{y \in T} R(x,y)$.

Comment: @ttnphns: “I perceive...” You're right, every single element of either $A$ or $B$ must belong to exactly one cluster.

Comment: @ttnphns: I'd be okay with an algorithm that assumes a fixed number of clusters as input, but it would be nice to have an algorithm that proposes the number of clusters as a part of the solution. In that case, the measure I proposed above is no good, because the optimal solution would simply be to treat the entire data set as a single cluster.

Comment: The thing is that I'm not sure it is a classic "cluster analysis" task. It looks that the groups you want to form should be disjoint by its content (membership) - it is the only difference. Clusters have to proximated vis-a-vis each other based on something else besides that. So far, I see that you request 1) groups are disjoint (in the sence outlined above), 2) summed frequency within each cluster is hopefully maximized. Is there anything else that you want?

Comment: @ttnphns: Oh, sorry, I wasn't aware that clustering had a more precise technical definition. What would be a better term in this case, so that I can edit the question's title?

Comment: You (or we) may edit it later. But tell me please, are the two points in my last comments is (only) what you need? That is, you want to form some disjoint (by row/col indices) groups of cells, each group is homogeneous in that it tends to contain cells with only high enough frequencies. Is that so?

Comment: @ttnphns: You're completely right about the first point. Regarding the second point, what you describe is one valid possibility, but the metric to optimize might be more complicated than just the summed frequency, e.g., it could be the sum of squares of each cluster's summed frequency. (Here I'd like to know more about the tradeoff between computational simplicity and output quality.)